# Elasticsearch and MongoDB n-gram indexing for each mongo document in collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, elasticsearch

I am an Elasticsearch newbie, and came across recommendations on using ES with MongoDB for text indexing/search capabilities.

What I am trying to achieve though is analyze the text in my Mongo collection, then build an association between similar content based upon textual context.

For example:

```
Collection A => 
{
id:1, 
text: 'The sly Fox dug a tunnel under the Fence to snatch a Hen',

}
    {
id:2, 
text: 'Jack the farmer built a fence to protect his Hens',
associated: [id4,id1,...]
}
    {
id:3, 
text: 'Jack listened to his radio and called it a night',
}
{
id:4, 
text: 'The farmer Jack plowed the field'
}
```

The system should then associate these documents in the following order:

- id2 <==> id4 # "The farmer Jack" - n-gram
- id2 <==> id1 # Fence & Hens
- ... and so on.

One inefficient way of solving this, is once I have created an index of Collection A in Elasticsearch, I can then write a batch process to cycle through each n-gram and search for it in ES, then push the results back into collection A (See association).

I presume there must be an easier way of doing this, and that I might be missing something. Is there ? If so, what is it or where can I find good references about it ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to do this in ElasticSearch. The easiest way would be to make a second search at runtime in order to retreive related content.

As it is dynamic content, event if you index it, it may not be updated at some point except if the index size is fixed.

if you really want to index the result, I would say your batch is a solution